# Stop MediaPlayer

Tags: java, android, media-player

I made an android application where you can click buttons to play sounds. Every time, you click the button, a new MediaPlayer is getting created and the problem is, when you push a button during another sound is still playing, they are playing at the same time, but I want, that the previous sounds stops when you push a button. I already tried this code but my application crashes every time I press the button:

```
MediaPlayer mp;
Button button;

button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            if(mp.isPlaying()){

                mp.stop();

            }

            mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.sound);
            mp.start();

        }});
```

Is there a way to solve my problem?

Comment: post the stacktrace from when your app crashes.

Answer (score 2):

It might be crashing because 'mp' is not initialized. Try this:

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        //if mp exists and is playing...
        if(mp != null && mp.isPlaying()){

            mp.stop();

        }

        mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.sound);
        mp.start();

    }});
```

**EDIT** You could also avoid checking for null by initializing 'mp' when you declare it on top.

For instance, instead of checking if mp != null. Change your declaration of 'mp' from:

```
MediaPlayer mp;
```

to

```
MediaPlayer mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.sound);
```

and your onclick method could look like:

```
public void onClick(View v) {

    if(mp.isPlaying()) {
        mp.stop();
    }

    //start mp from beginning

}
```

Comment: already tried your code with the same error :/, but the second thing i don't really get

Comment: The code you suggest is the best way. as opposed to intialising it when not needed. (in this case). @LennartSchoch You are going to hve to post a logcat. Else its just guess work. Plus im pretty sure you are suppose to call `.release()`

Answer (score 0):

It seems like starting too many MediaPlayer isn't good, because when i click the sounds a couple times, the app crashes. I already changed mp.start to mp.reset and release.

Comment: Make another question, answers section is for answers.

Answer (score 0):

## Notes

- You have to release the player before creating a new one
- I would not bet on isPlaying() check to stop the player; since you don't need it release it!

## Code

```
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

       if(mp != null) { 
           mp.release(); 
       }
       mp = MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(), R.raw.sound);
       mp.start();

    }});
```